# Can I write a program that can repeat a diagram for x number of rows

Tags: python

[image: The layout and expected output]

I have some execution problems in doing that.Cannot make it loop for the times I want.My code is like that:

```
def question_6_2():
    a = ['*','#','$']
    b = [1,4,7] 
    group1=(a[0]*b[0]+"\n")
    group2=(a[1]*b[1]+"\n")
    group3=(a[2]*b[2]+"\n")
    total_group=[group1,group2,group3]*i
    row_num=int(input("Please input the number of rows you want: "))
    for i in range(row_num+1):
        print(total_group[i])
```

Comment: Please expand on "some execution problems".

Comment: Above diagram? where is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a minor change --> `print(total_group[i])` to `print(total_group[i%3])`

Your function should be:

```
def question_6_2():
    a = ['*','#','$']
    b = [1,4,7] 
    group1=(a[0]*b[0]+"\n")
    group2=(a[1]*b[1]+"\n")
    group3=(a[2]*b[2]+"\n")
    total_group=[group1,group2,group3]
    row_num=int(input("Please input the number of rows you want: "))
    for i in range(row_num):
        print(total_group[i%3])

question_6_2()
```

---

**Output1:**

Please input the number of rows you want: 5

```
*

####

$$$$$$$

*

####
```

---

**Output2:**

```
Please input the number of rows you want: 10
*

####

$$$$$$$

*

####

$$$$$$$

*

####

$$$$$$$

*
```

Comment: Thanks for your guidance! May I ask what is the % in the square bracket for?

Comment: % = remainder. since you want to come back in a cyclic way so better to use modulus.

Comment: suppose if you have list = `[1,2,3] ` now you say I want to get the in cyclic way `(1->2->3->1->2->3->1)`  say 7 times. then use modulus. when i becomes 3 then 3%3 =0 so it will go back to start. if i =4 , 4%3 =1 then go to 1st position and so on.